# replacing a pandas dataframe row overwrites all columns' dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

When I replace a row of a df, it causes an existing column of dtype=int to become float. I would like to keep it as int.

I create the df:

```
testdate = pd.datetime(2014, 1, 1)
adddata = {'intcol':0,'floatcol':0.0}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=adddata, index=pd.date_range(testdate, periods=1))
```

As desired, one column is int and the other is float, as confirmed by `df.dtypes`:

```
floatcol    float64
intcol        int64
dtype: object
```

Then I overwrite an existing row (in this case there's only 1) using `df.ix[testdate] = pd.Series(adddata)`. I purposely use the same data to show the issue: the intcol has become float. `df.dtypes`:

```
floatcol    float64
intcol      float64
dtype: object
```

Note that I can change the cells individually (e.g. `df.ix[testdate,'floatcol'] = 0.0`) and the column dtypes are maintained, but in reality I have far more than 2 columns that I want to overwrite simultaneously so doing them one at a time is cumbersome.

Comment: see this question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044766/adding-row-to-pandas-dataframe-changes-dtype/22045011#22045011. This is currently a bug, best to use ``append`` to avoid the dtype change

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I had seen that link and did try append, but I'm replacing a row, not adding one, so I didn't think the enlargement problem applied. I did try append though to see if it would let me overwrite, but it oddly seems to give me duplicate index entries, e.g. I get two rows with date 2014-01-01. I couldn't figure out how to get append to overwrite the existing row, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What you are trying to do in general won't work. Dtypes are column based. Creating a Series (e.g the row), will assign a combined (and highest) dtype of the values which it is passed; a particular value will not be preserved. When you assign a row in its entirety the values are then coerced to the column dtypes (which can also potentially change the dtype of the column).

Comment: Doing this kind of assignment is almost not the right way to go about this. You are much better off of creating the new data, selecting the data you want out of the existing frame, then ``concat`` together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

interesting that even specifying the data type as `object` does not help:

```
>>> df.loc[testdate,:] = pd.Series(adddata, dtype='object')
>>> df.dtypes
floatcol    float64
intcol      float64
dtype: object
```

someone may have a better solution, but i noticed that this works:

```
>>> df.loc[testdate,:] = pd.Series(list(adddata.values()), adddata.keys(), dtype='object')
>>> df.dtypes
floatcol    float64
intcol        int64
dtype: object
```

but, if the row values are in `dict` format, probably this would be easier:

```
>>> df.loc[testdate,:] = list(map(adddata.get, df.columns))
>>> df.dtypes
floatcol    float64
intcol        int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to python so it's taking me a while to understand your solution, and why it would work when straight pd.Series does not. For the moment I have a working but not so graceful 2 line for loop: for i in adddata: df.ix[testdate,i] = adddata[i]

Comment: +1. Your last method could also be written as `df.loc[testdate] = map(adddata.get, df.columns)`.

Comment: @unutbu in python 3 `map` returns a map object as opposed to a list, which causes `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()`

Comment: Just came back to this and realized that your last method also gracefully handles the situation where the dict keys don't entirely match the columns (some extras and/or some missing). Seems it's about 30% faster than looping too.