# Error while trying to write pandas dataframe to oracle using to_sql

Tags: python, pandas

Python: 2.7.6
Pandas: 0.14
SQLAlchemy: 0.9.4

While trying to write a dataframe to an Oracle DB using Pandas to_sql function, I get the following error

```
TypeError: expecting string, unicode or buffer object
```

The Dataframe was created by appending 2 seperate dataframes together, df1 and df2. 
df1 info is as follows:

```
Int64Index: 20 entries, 0 to 19
Data columns (total 19 columns):
AID                20 non-null int64
CHARGE_OFF_AMT     20 non-null object
FEE_PAID           20 non-null object
GRADE              20 non-null object
INT_PMT            20 non-null object
LATE_FEE_PMT       20 non-null object
OUTSTANDING_AMT    20 non-null object
PERIOD             20 non-null object
PRIN_PMT           20 non-null object
PRODUCT            20 non-null int64
PURCHASES_AMT      20 non-null object
PURCHASES_COUNT    20 non-null int64
RECOVERY_PMT       20 non-null object
TERM               20 non-null int64
TOTAL_PMT          20 non-null object
WHOLE_FLAG         20 non-null object
ORDERS_AMT         16 non-null float64
ORDERS_COUNT       16 non-null float64
IN_FUNDING         16 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(4), object(12)
```

df2 info is as follows:

```
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 6 columns):
AID            1 non-null int64
PERIOD         1 non-null object
DEPOSITS       1 non-null int64
WITHDRAWALS    1 non-null int64
BONUS          1 non-null int64
TOTAL_CASH     1 non-null object
dtypes: int64(4), object(2)
```

I am then appending df2 to df1 resulting in final_d:

```
>>final_d = df1.append(df2)
>>final_d.info()
Int64Index: 21 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 23 columns):
AID                21 non-null int64
BONUS              1 non-null float64
CHARGE_OFF_AMT     20 non-null object
DEPOSITS           1 non-null float64
FEE_PAID           20 non-null object
GRADE              20 non-null object
INT_PMT            20 non-null object
IN_FUNDING         16 non-null float64
LATE_FEE_PMT       20 non-null object
ORDERS_AMT         16 non-null float64
ORDERS_COUNT       16 non-null float64
OUTSTANDING_AMT    20 non-null object
PERIOD             21 non-null object
PRIN_PMT           20 non-null object
PRODUCT            20 non-null float64
PURCHASES_AMT      20 non-null object
PURCHASES_COUNT    20 non-null float64
RECOVERY_PMT       20 non-null object
TERM               20 non-null float64
TOTAL_CASH         1 non-null object
TOTAL_PMT          20 non-null object
WHOLE_FLAG         20 non-null object
WITHDRAWALS        1 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(9), int64(1), object(13)
```

Finally, I am attempting to write final_d to an oracle 11g DB.

```
>>db = sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://foo:bar@(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE=on) (FAILOVER=ON) \
              (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.address.com)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) \
               (SERVICE_NAME = replica)))")
    notes_cash = all_notes_info.append(all_cash_info)
>>final_d.to_sql('data_table', db, if_exists='append', index=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 950, in to_sql
    index_label=index_label)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 440, in to_sql
    index_label=index_label)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 815, in to_sql
    table.insert()
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 584, in insert
    self.pd_sql.execute(ins, data_list)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 783, in execute
    return self.engine.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1682, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 720, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 317, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 817, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 947, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1111, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 917, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/adsouza/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/cx_oracle.py", line 916, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
TypeError: expecting string, unicode or buffer object
```

I was able to successfully write df1 and df2 to oracle using this approach but am unable to write the appended dataframe.

Here is a sample of the final df:

```
      AID       BONUS      CHARGE_OFF_AMT       DEPOSITS  FEE_PAID   GRADE  \
0  5819681       NaN      36600.565886430978       NaN        0        E   

        INT_PMT          IN_FUNDING  LATE_FEE_PMT  ORDERS_AMT     ...      \
0  113099.457782700363      257875        76.07     1091450     ...       

       PRIN_PMT          PRODUCT    PURCHASES_AMT PURCHASES_COUNT  RECOVERY_PMT  \
0  290035.650142431736       1        574400            2767             0   

  TERM  TOTAL_CASH            TOTAL_PMT  WHOLE_FLAG WITHDRAWALS  
0   36         NaN  403211.177925132099  FRACTIONAL         NaN
```

Comment: please provide ur code..or u will be given large amount of downvotes.please follow the rules to write a question in SO. ur work,error,expected output

Comment: Specifically what is certainly needed here: pandas version, db driver, example of your dataframe (or at least `df.info()`), your full function call and full error message.

Comment: Hmm, strange as it works for the individual dfs, but not for the concatenated. Can you try to see if this has something to do with `NaN`s? (they are not yet really supported) Eg with ``df.fillna(None)`` or `df.fillna('a string')` and see if the issue still exists.

Comment: Also, what is the content of the object types? Are it strings? Maybe show a `df.head()`

Comment: Where you able to check it the cause could be the `NaN` values? (see my comment above)

Comment: I have a feeling its because of the NaN's but cant find a way to get rid of them.  fillna(0), fillna('0') and dropna() did not do the trick. Looks like this is a known issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044766/adding-row-to-pandas-dataframe-changes-dtype

Comment: How does it not work? The `NaN` values just stay? `df.fillna(0)` or `df.fillna('0')` should normally work. Or you can also try `df.fillna('ffill')` (that may not make sense for your data, but just to check what the issue could be)

Comment: Heres what the df.head looks like after doing any of the above df.fillna variations: '>>> final_data.head(1)
       AID  BONUS      CHARGE_OFF_AMT  DEPOSITS FEE_PAID GRADE   '
0  5819681    NaN  36600.565886430978       NaN        0     E...

Comment: @Alan sorry, late reply. But maybe you can ask an new (seperate) question about why the fillna does not work (it is a bit difficult to discuss it here in the comments)