# Pandas Dataframe automatic typecasting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting

I am working with a pandas dataframe and need several columns (x & y in the example below) to be an integer and one column to be a float (l).  It appears that assigning a new row with a float in it recasts the whole dataframe as a float.  Why is this and how do I prevent it?

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[[3103, 1189, 1]],index = None, columns = ['y', 'x', 'l'], dtype = int)
print data.y
data.ix[1] = (3, 3, 3.4)
print data.y
```

Which produces:

```
0    3103
Name: y, dtype: int32
0    3103
1       3
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

Comment: You will find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044766/adding-row-to-pandas-dataframe-changes-dtype

Comment: Disregard my answer, the one that @IanS linked is a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can recast all of the other columns after each addition using:

```
data['y'] = data['y'].astype(int)
```

Not the most efficient solution if you need to add a lot of columns on the fly. Alternatively you could create the entire data frame using Series in advance and type the whole thing a creation time instead if that's an option.